# Query working in SQL server, but not in RODBC

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I'm trying to run the following query in `RODBC`:

```
library(RODBC)

sql <- paste("SELECT * INTO #DataQuery FROM ( SELECT * FROM [DSMM_PPCreporting].[dbo].[DSMM_FACT_TABLE] WITH (NOLOCK)  WHERE [DSMM_FACT_TABLE].Client_ID = 85 AND VenueSource=1   AND TimeStamp BETWEEN  '10/1/2014' AND '10/13/2014' AND Venue_ID in (1,14)) xxxx") 
sql <- paste(sql, "SELECT Timestamp as Date, isnull(FlexCategory.FlexCategoryName,'UNASSIGNED') AS [Flex Category], isnull(Venue.Venue,'UNASSIGNED') AS [Venue], isnull(CategoryName,'UNASSIGNED') AS [Campaign], isnull(Device,'UNASSIGNED') AS [Device], ")
sql <- paste(sql, "round(SUM(isNull(cost,0)),2) AS [Cost ($)],SUM(isNull(VenueConversions1PC,0)) +SUM(isNull(VenueConversions,0))  AS [Venue Leads] ")
sql <- paste(sql, "INTO #FlexCategory FROM #DataQuery DSMM_FACT_TABLE WITH (NOLOCK) ")
sql <- paste(sql, "LEFT JOIN Device WITH (NOLOCK) ON DSMM_FACT_TABLE.Device_ID = Device.Device_ID") 
sql <- paste(sql, "LEFT JOIN Venue WITH (NOLOCK) ON DSMM_FACT_TABLE.Venue_ID = Venue.Venue_ID")
sql <- paste(sql, "LEFT JOIN Category WITH (NOLOCK) ON DSMM_FACT_TABLE.Category_ID = Category.Category_ID")
sql <- paste(sql, "LEFT JOIN FlexCategory WITH (NOLOCK) ON Category.FlexCategory_ID = FlexCategory.FlexCategory_ID")
sql <- paste(sql, "GROUP BY Timestamp, isnull(FlexCategory.FlexCategoryName,'UNASSIGNED') ,")
sql <- paste(sql, "isnull(CategoryName,'UNASSIGNED'), ")
sql <- paste(sql, "isnull(Venue.Venue,'UNASSIGNED'),")
sql <- paste(sql, " isnull(Device,'UNASSIGNED')")
sql <- paste(sql, "ORDER BY [Venue Leads] DESC")
sql <- paste(sql, "SELECT * FROM #FlexCategory WITH (NOLOCK)")
##sql <- paste(sql, "DROP TABLE #FlexCategory")
##sql <- paste(sql, "DROP TABLE #DataQuery")

# Connecting R to DSMM and running the SQL query there
connect <- odbcConnect("DSMM")
system.time(Data <- sqlQuery(connect, sql))
close(connect)
```

this query works perfectly inside microsoft SQL server:

```
SELECT * INTO #DataQuery FROM ( SELECT * FROM [DSMM_PPCreporting].[dbo].[DSMM_FACT_TABLE] WITH (NOLOCK)  WHERE [DSMM_FACT_TABLE].Client_ID = 85 AND VenueSource=1   AND TimeStamp BETWEEN  '10/1/2014' AND '10/13/2014' AND Venue_ID in (1,14)) xxxx SELECT Timestamp as Date, isnull(FlexCategory.FlexCategoryName,'UNASSIGNED') AS [Flex Category], isnull(Venue.Venue,'UNASSIGNED') AS [Venue], isnull(CategoryName,'UNASSIGNED') AS [Campaign], isnull(Device,'UNASSIGNED') AS [Device],  round(SUM(isNull(cost,0)),2) AS [Cost ($)],SUM(isNull(VenueConversions1PC,0)) +SUM(isNull(VenueConversions,0))  AS [Venue Leads]  INTO #FlexCategory FROM #DataQuery DSMM_FACT_TABLE WITH (NOLOCK)  LEFT JOIN Device WITH (NOLOCK) ON DSMM_FACT_TABLE.Device_ID = Device.Device_ID LEFT JOIN Venue WITH (NOLOCK) ON DSMM_FACT_TABLE.Venue_ID = Venue.Venue_ID LEFT JOIN Category WITH (NOLOCK) ON DSMM_FACT_TABLE.Category_ID = Category.Category_ID LEFT JOIN FlexCategory WITH (NOLOCK) ON Category.FlexCategory_ID = FlexCategory.FlexCategory_ID GROUP BY Timestamp, isnull(FlexCategory.FlexCategoryName,'UNASSIGNED') , isnull(CategoryName,'UNASSIGNED'),  isnull(Venue.Venue,'UNASSIGNED'),  isnull(Device,'UNASSIGNED') ORDER BY [Venue Leads] DESC SELECT * FROM #FlexCategory WITH (NOLOCK)
```

I know that my SQL connection works perfectly, and a different query that i'm using works great, for example the following code works great in R and loads a data frame into the global environment:

```
sql <- "SELECT  TK_ID, Client_ID, tk.searchterm_id, SearchTerm,  RegionName, CityName, Timestamp FROM [DSMM_PPCreporting].[dbo].[tk] "
sql <- paste(sql, "left join [DSMM_PPCreporting].[dbo].searchterm (nolock) on [DSMM_PPCreporting].[dbo].tk.searchterm_id=[DSMM_PPCreporting].[dbo].searchterm.searchterm_id ")
sql <- paste(sql, "left join [DSMM_PPCreporting].[dbo].Region (nolock) on [DSMM_PPCreporting].[dbo].tk.Region_ID=[DSMM_PPCreporting].[dbo].Region.Region_ID ")
sql <- paste(sql, "left join [DSMM_PPCreporting].[dbo].City (nolock) on [DSMM_PPCreporting].[dbo].tk.city_id=[DSMM_PPCreporting].[dbo].city.city_ID ")
#sql <- paste(sql, "where convert(Date, [LastUpdate]) = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0)") 
sql <- paste(sql, "where convert(Date, [LastUpdate]) >= '2014-10-15' and convert(Date, [LastUpdate]) <= dateadd(day, datediff(day, 1, GETDATE()), 0)")
# Connecting R to DSMM and running the SQL query there
connect <- odbcConnect("DSMM")
system.time(Data <- sqlQuery(connect, sql))
close(connect)
```

I know that some `SQL server` commands don't work in `RODBC`, could that be the problem?, if so can some one point out to me which SQL server functions won't work in `RODBC`, so ill try to change the query (if possible).

I tried to find some info on which SQL Server commands, don't work in `RODBC` , without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `RODBC` does not support inner select statements:

This code works:

```
sql <- paste("SELECT TimeStamp FROM [DSMM_PPCreporting].[dbo].[DSMM_FACT_TABLE]  WHERE [DSMM_FACT_TABLE].Client_ID = 85 AND VenueSource=1   AND TimeStamp BETWEEN  '10/1/2014' AND '10/13/2014' AND Venue_ID in (1,14)") 
connect <- odbcConnect("DSMM")
Data <- sqlQuery(connect, sql)
close(connect)
```

While this doesn't:

```
sql <- paste("SELECT *  FROM (SELECT TimeStamp FROM [DSMM_PPCreporting].[dbo].[DSMM_FACT_TABLE]  WHERE [DSMM_FACT_TABLE].Client_ID = 85 AND VenueSource=1   AND TimeStamp BETWEEN  '10/1/2014' AND '10/13/2014' AND Venue_ID in (1,14))") 
connect <- odbcConnect("DSMM")
Data <- sqlQuery(connect, sql)
close(connect)
```

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem using RJDBC on an ingres database and I believe the cause was a memory problem.

I was running a large query from R with an inner select (which would also have a large amount of data). It did not work and returned an error like

> Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for "..

Running the same query directly on the database worked perfectly fine (it took a while though). At first I also thought it could be the inner select. However, I had another query with an inner select which was working fine, and when I only ran the part inside the inner select it did not work either.

I have concluded it was a memory issue, since later, when there were less users using the database, the same query did run from R (and it still does). 
Certainly it is not so that RODBC or RJDBC does not support inner selects. I have worked with inner selects with both configurations and they work fine.

For me this query had a particularly large amount of data obtained by the inner select. And I think that this is the reason why at the same time I could run another similar query, using only a smaller timeframe (and hence there was less data obtained by the inner select).
Hope this helps with figuring out what is wrong.

Comment: Sound interesting, ill give it a look some time ,Wow this is an old one:)